# Notificaction Hub and SQL Server

Tags: visual-studio, azure, notifications

Can somebody help me how to send **Notifications using Azure SQL Server** ?

Lets say I want to create an Application where the user **adds, updates, or deletes a schedule** .
If the scheduler runs and finds that it has to send  notifications for a particular time, say 6:00 pm . I was wondering if there is any way I can use SQL Server so it can send the notification when called by the scheduled job. ?

Comment: What do you mean, sending notifications using SQL Database? Not sure what you're asking. Also, I don't understand the relevance of Visual Studio in the question. You should probably edit your question to explain better. As it is currently written, it will likely be closed.

Comment: I have to create an Mobile Application using SQL and Notification Hubs where I have to send notifications using SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server cannot send notifications. What is your scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, it is not possible with the SQL Azure. In SQL Server, you have [Query Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188323(v=sql.105)). If you want to use SQL Azure, then i would offer you to implement the notifications functionality in your own application. So, application, when making the changes to the database, sends the notification as well. Somehow, for example, using [Azure Queues](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-azure-and-service-bus-queues-compared-contrasted/) - with the information about columns updated.

Comment: Do you know is there is any code example ? or maybe tutorial?